# What is objc's ->?

Tags: objective-c

What does objc's `->` stand for ?
Is there any difference from just dot chain?
e.g. `self.delegate` , `self->delegate`

Comment: Dot syntax will go through the objc getter, that arrow syntax is used to simply access the raw ivar

Comment: You should know C/C++ before you tackle Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

`->` in Objective-C is the same as `->` in C. It is a field access operator that lets you dereference a pointer (as opposed to dot `.` operator, which requires a struct).

What's confusing about it in Objective-C is the dot syntax on pointers for accessing properties. So the rules for choosing a dot vs. `->` become a little confusing:

- Use dot `.` for accessing Objective-C properties on Objective-C objects, which are always accessed through pointers
- Use arrow `->` for accessing Objective-C instance variables on Objective-C objects, and for accessing fields on C structures through pointers
- Use dot `.` for accessing fields on C structures.